# What does "apparently" mean in this conversation?

Tags: spoken-english, exam-questions

> "Now we've got to give a bit of feedback about last term's modules - just short comments, **apparently**. Shall we do that now?"
>
> "OK. So medical terminology."

I know "apparently" has a meaning "obvious", but after going through these sentences I don't understand what mentioned is obvious.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? "Apparently" doesn't mean "obvious". Also, to know what the speaker means here, we'd need some more of the context before this quote. It's unclear from this short quote why "apparently" was used.

Comment: Please provide the source of this quote.

Comment: I'm not able to provide more of the context since these two sentences are the beginning of the conversation. @James K

Comment: @jackS  I didn't ask for context.  I asked for source. This comes from ielts listening 2017 part 3 https://ieltstrainingonline.com/audioscripts-cambridge-ielts-17-listening-test-01/

Comment: Always attribute, i.e cite your sources,  texts, extracts, sentences, including manual instructions that you have not created yourself. Why this fundamental rule, which by the way helps users put into context questions asking about meaning, steadfastly ignored by a small but productive minority of users?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks context and the source is not cited.

Answer (score 1):

What is "apparent" is that the feedback should be in the form of short comments.  It doesn't mean that this is obvious, instead it means that the speaker believes that the comments should be short from the situation or wider context.

For example.  If the speaker is holding a form, and the feedback is to be written on the form, and the form only has a small space for each comment, then the speaker might think "Because the space for the comments is small, the comments should be short"

It does not say that the comments should be short, so it is not explicit.  Instead the speaker has worked it out so it is apparent.

Comment: See [these](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/apparently) possible uses of the word.